# Associating onchange to all fields in a form

Tags: jquery, onchange

I am trying to associate onchange event to all fields in a form using jquery. The code is following

```
$("#myform").change( function(){
       somethingIsChanged=true;
});
```

It works well but the issue is if I click on a button in my form operationFormSave is set to true in that case as well. So how can I add onchange on all fields in a form ignoring the buttons or input=button

Comment: `$("#myform input:not(:button)").change(` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$('input').not('input[type="button"]').change(function() {
    somethingIsChanged=true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class for that

```
$(".myclassedit").change( function(){
    somethingIsChanged=true;
});
```

or even if your input's are the same type, you can do this

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
    somethingIsChanged=true;
});
```